# Update product from a module in prestashop

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I have to update the `price` and `quantity` values of specific `products` in a database.

As I understand, simply executing sql commands is not a great option since there are a lot of tables which have similar informations. I have read that `Product()` object should be created.

How should I create the `Product` object and then update it in the database?

Comment: Executing in SQL commands is still a good choice. You just have to specify your query to a unique ID. For a specific product, it must have a unique ID, then your query would run like `UPDATE products SET price = ? AND quantity = ? WHERE uniqueid = ?`

Comment: @LoganWayne it is not a good choice, since Presta's database is a bit more complicated and as UnLoCo mentioned below, products may have multiple combinations of quantities and so on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can check the class `ProductCore` in `classes/Product.php` for various methods and properties

Generally, you would write some code like this

```
//assuming you have the product id as $id_product
$product = new Product($id_product);
//change the product properties
$product->quantity = 10;
$product->price = 60.2;
//save the changes
$product->save();
```

**Edit:**
To update the quantity you can use this method:

```
StockAvailable::updateQuantity($id_product, $id_product_attribute, $delta_quantity, $id_shop = null);
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, maybe you know how I could get Product object by reference, not by id?

Comment: You have to always use the `id` to get the product. I don't know what you mean by reference, can you explain more?

Comment: products in PrestaShop have unique references (like barcodes). But that doesn't matter, simple SQL query returns ID without any problems. I still have one question left. It seems like quantity doesn't update correctly. Price updated just fine (I am looking through products in admin panel), but quantity is still the same. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Thank you. I will most definitely have to look through documentation more carefully, because now for me it makes no sense why Presta is built this way. I mean, why would you need to update product quantity through other class..

Comment: One reason is that a product can have more than one quantity because it can have more than one combination, it will make more sense with experience